# Image for equation is not generated when compiling with make4ht and XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, tex4ht, make4ht

When compiling with `make4ht` and `XeLaTeX` engine, the images for equations are not created. Here is a sample code to illustrate it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
l(\Lambda)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{w=1}^{q} (z_{i w} \ln (\lambda_{i w}) - \lambda_{i w} - \ln (z_{i w}!))
\label{eq-poisson}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I'm compiling with:

```
make4ht -u -x example
```

The generated HTML file expects an image file:

```
<img src='example0x.png' class='math-display' alt='      ∑n  ∑q
l(Λ) =       (ziwln(λiw )− λiw − ln(ziw!))
       i=1 w=1
' />
```

Note that the alternative text also does not help much to grasp what is the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pictures are created using DVI to output image format conversion. Various tools are used for the conversion, `dvipng` is used by default.

XeTeX produces different type of DVI file than PDFTeX or LuaTeX and it seems that `dvipng` doesn't support it. You can see an error message when you add the `-a debug` option to `make4ht`:

```
System call: dvipng -T tight -D 144 -bg Transparent -pp 2:2 sample.idv -o sample0x.png
--- Warning --- System return: 512
```

You can try the SVG output instead. It uses `dvisvgm` for the conversion, which seems to better support modern DVI versions. Add the `"svg"` option to the `make4ht` call:

```
make4ht -u -x example "svg"
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to get a better alt text?

Comment: @LEo in theory yes you can put the original TeX code into alt, but it wouldn't be easy. Consider also [MathJax rendered math](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Configurations.html#x8-770007.19.3).